# Insert Affiliate tracking link into my HTML

Tags: hyperlink, tracking

i'm new into Marketing and i got an opportunity to offer a few products in my web site. The company that i had the offers from sent me this Tracking Link: [https://adswapper.g2afse.com/click?pid=210&offer_id=586&sub1={clickid}&sub2={pid}&sub3={subsource}&sub4={device_id}&sub5={app_name}](https://adswapper.g2afse.com/click?pid=210&offer_id=586&sub1=%7Bclickid%7D&sub2=%7Bpid%7D&sub3=%7Bsubsource%7D&sub4=%7Bdevice_id%7D&sub5=%7Bapp_name%7D)

How do i add that in to my website? So when the customer click on the offer the tracking link would work in between the action and the Main link final uRL which is https://www.audiobooks.co.uk/signup

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use a hyperlink for this

```
<a href="https://adswapper.g2afse.com/click?pid=210&offer_id=586&sub1=%7Bclickid%7D&sub2=%7Bpid%7D&sub3=%7Bsubsource%7D&sub4=%7Bdevice_id%7D&sub5=%7Bapp_name%7D">Click here</a>
```

You're Welcomed if this helps!!

Comment: but how do i make when clients click on the link https://www.audiobooks.co.uk/signup that TRACKING LINK gets activated? i sent more details below

Answer (score 0):

So to be more specific the Advertisers gave me the HTML for the campaign and i wanna to know where to insert the TRACKING LINK i will be using into the HTML.

```
<a href="https://www.audiobooks.co.uk/signup" target="_blank">
```

So when the clients click on that link i need to collect the information using that TRAKING LINK the AdSwapper has which is [https://adswapper.g2afse.com/click?pid=210&offer_id=586&sub1={clickid}&sub2={pid}&sub3={subsource}&sub4={device_id}&sub5={app_name}](https://adswapper.g2afse.com/click?pid=210&offer_id=586&sub1=%7Bclickid%7D&sub2=%7Bpid%7D&sub3=%7Bsubsource%7D&sub4=%7Bdevice_id%7D&sub5=%7Bapp_name%7D)
Thanks for the help, i'm new on this